# PDE solution via characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> Solve for $u \equiv u(x,y)$
> $$-y u_x+xu_y=0$$

I have to use characteristic method and I have a little problem with the solution proposed. My attempt starts considering auxiliary system
$$\frac{dx}{ds}=-y,\frac{dy}{ds}=x \label{eq_1}\tag{1}$$

Translated with separable variable ODE
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y}{x}\label{eq_2}\tag{2}$$

And I found the solution
$$y = \frac{c}{x}\label{eq_3}\tag{3}$$

Here troubles begin because while the proposed solution follow exactly $\eqref{eq_1},\eqref{eq_2}$, then the solution of $\eqref{eq_2}$ is said to be
$$x^2+y^2=c$$

Am I missing something? I've been on this quite a bit but I could not figure out what is wrong and if solutions are equivalent. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, even after the correction rightly pointed out by Hans Lundmark, you miss many solutions because the general solution is $u(x,y)=F(x^2+y^2)$ with any function $F$. This function has to be determined if some valid boundary condition is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide the two equations in (1), you get $dy/dx = x/(-y)$, not $(-y)/x$.